# Create a downloadable ios link of app not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, app-store

I'm trying to upload my flutter app to either [deployninja](http://www.deployninja.com/), [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/), or testflight.
I currently have an expired apple developers membership.

In Xcode I went to Product > Archive > Distribute. When ic click on any of the export options, I get an error saying

> Team "Jessica (Personal Team)" is not enrolled in the Apple Developer Program.
>
> Distribution requires enrollment in the Apple Developer Program. Visit https://developer.apple.com/account to enroll.

How can I create a downloadable link for my app without uploading it to the app store yet?

Comment: Distributing an ad-how build requires your provisioning profile to contain the UDIDs of all devices that you want to be able to run your app. You can't add UDIDs without having a paid membership.

Comment: did you find this questions answer? if yes please tell me, thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's possible. You need to have an app created in itunes connect to get the appstore link (app id).

Answer (score -1):

You need an Apple Developer account. If you have it, you can use test flight to send your app to people without making it on the app store.

Another option is this: Your app is in the product section in Xcode

[image]

I don't know how to download this on iPhone but that is the application file.